# UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to return the data list and plot. They do display in the HTML code instead of web page. When I look at the terminal it shows `"UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail."`

```py
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd


def extract(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.FILES.get('document'):
            file = request.FILES['document']

            if 'data' in request.POST:
                data = df = pd.read_excel(file)
                mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000
                plt.plot(data["time"], data["make"], label='male')
                plt.plot(data["time"], data["female"], label='female')

                plt.xlabel('T')
                plt.ylabel('M and F')
                plt.legend()

                buffer = BytesIO()
                plt.savefig(buffer, format='png')
                buffer.seek(0)
                image_png = buffer.getvalue()
                buffer.close()

                graphic = base64.b64encode(image_png)
                graphic = graphic.decode('utf-8')


                dic_result = {'graphic': graphic}

                dataa = []
                for index in range(len(data["make"])):
                   data.append(tuple(dataa["male"][index], dataa["female"][index]))

                return render(request, 'bothdata.html', {'data': dataa}, dic_result)


    return render(request, 'extract.html')
```

Comment: That's just a warning. If the code works, is there an issue?

Answer (score 26):

try this, it worked for me

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

Agg, is a non-interactive backend that can only write to files.
For more information and other ways of solving it see https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html

Answer (score 0):

It's just warning, it will run but can be a really painful problem. I'm not exactly an expert but I'm having the same warning, and it can be worse if you try to use matplotlib in a Thread besides Main Thread. For some reason matplotlib don't work well on Threads, which can cause your aplication to crash.